# Does Z-Stack Supports Keil Compiler?

Tags: keil, iar, zigbee, home-automation

I will try to do a project with z-stack home automation profile for smart home automation with zigbee. But, according to my researches z-stack is only supoorts IAR compilers. Does anybody know that is there any version of z-stack that supports Keil compilers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TI ZStack SDK it is only supported on IAR.